# CSS3 centering text inside triangle

Tags: html, css

I have a triangle image at the top left corner of the page, and some text that needs to be centered inside it at the bottom (using CSS3 `transform: rotate`).  I can do it with some positioning/margins but it does not look the same across browsers, it appears a little to the left or right.

Is there a way to center it so it displays evenly in all browsers?

I made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VScFS/53/).  Here I'm using CSS to make the triangle but in reality I'm using an image.

I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset?
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know base width of triangle, then set `width:` of text container equal to base width, `text-align: center;` and rotate. Just make sure, that center point of text container is also center point of base.

After some calculations, I made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VScFS/57/. It looks same in Chrome and Firefox.

Anyway, I think the problem is related to absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you atlavis.  I had some trouble with the text container div, I'd set it to the same width as the triangle's base but for some reason the text would split in 2 lines in chrome (I think it renders the font bigger than other browsers).  I had to give the div some extra width but then the text wouldn't look centered in opera and FF.  Based on your idea I did some calculations and managed to get it pretty close to how I wanted it.