# Inclided text inside half square box

Tags: css

I have a css to draw a half square box

```
.box-tri {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 30px solid rgb(217, 224, 231);
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(217, 224, 231);
}
```

Now what i should do if i want to write a text parallel to the diagonal of the box but inside the box.[image]

Comment: If you mean 'incline' then you can use the rotate transform: `transform: rotate(30deg);` in css

Comment: when i use transform it is rotating the half square box also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a child element to contain the text and rotated it with CSS `transform`:

```
<div class="box-tri">
    <span>Label</span>
</div>
```

```
.box-tri {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 30px solid rgb(217, 224, 231);
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(217, 224, 231);
}
.box-tri span {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-15px, -18px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-15px, -18px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-15px, -18px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1em;
    width:60px;
    height:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

One caveat is that longer text does not work very well. My version truncates it.

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/76UEK/1/)

---

In response to the other jsfiddle you found, I made the following changes to make the ribbon go from the top-right to the bottom-right:

```
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  ...
  top: -3px     // removed
  bottom: -3px; // added
}


.ribbon-green {
  ...
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);   // removed
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);   // removed
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);   // removed
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);   // removed
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);  // added
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);  // added
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);  // added
  -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);  // added
  ...
  top: 15px  // removed
  top: 45px; // added
}
```

It's not perfect, but try tweaking those values to polish it.

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/11665/)

Comment: Just noticed there's a [similar question/answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399057/css3-centering-text-inside-triangle) that might be helpful.

Comment: thanks....i was searching and came across http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/H6rQ6/1/ ... what changes i can do to make it appear bottom right instead of top right

Comment: I gave it a try, above.